# Make sidebar menu sticky with scrolling

Tags: css, sidebar, sticky

I would like to have my sidebar menu sticky when scrolling the page.
[image]

An example of **what I want** can be found here: https://codepen.io/hexagoncircle/pen/oNLZmvV
An code example of my website can be found here: https://codepen.io/darkinfore/pen/VwdwKKZ
You can see a live demo of my site here: https://ergonj4.joomlademo.nl/over-ergon/organisatie

The sidebar menu should stick under the top menu when scrolling just like the example does.

I tried to use

```
#scrollspy{
  position: sticky;
  top: 200px;
}
```

But that didn't work.
I can't get my sidebar menu to stick.

Can someone help me figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticky elements can only stick in their direct parent / wrapper.
So if you want it works, you have to specify a height on the direct parent of `scrollspy` :

[image: Screen of the correct parent sticky wrapper]

You can use Javascript to get `readthis` height and set this value on your sticky parent.

```
document.getElementById('module-365').style.height = document.getElementById('readthis').offsetHeight + 'px' ;
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand why it didnt work, now I do.